# Spring MongoDB query with or operator and text search

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

How can i build this MongoDB query with Spring Criteria?

```
{
  $or: [
    { "$text" : { "$search" : "570-11024" } },
    {"productDetails.code": "572-R110"}
  ]
}
```

It combines a fulltext index search with normal Where criteria with an orOperator.

Query's *orOperator(Criteria... criteria)* method takes only Criteria and no TextCriteria and also no CriteriaDefinition interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you are right, in spring data mongo you could do this,

```
final TextCriteria textCriteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny("570-11024");
final DBObject tc = textCriteria.getCriteriaObject();
final Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("productDetails.code").is("572-R110");
final DBObject co = criteria.getCriteriaObject();

BasicDBList or = new BasicDBList();
or.add(tc);
or.add(co);

DBObject qq = new BasicDBObject("$or", or);
// Use MongoTemplate to execute command
mongoTemplate.executeCommand(qq);
```

Comment: looks promising. any idea how to do this with reactive mongoTemplate?

Comment: `textCriteria.getCriteriaObject` returns a `Document` not `DBObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you currently cannot use the Query's orOperator method to combine Criteria and TextCriteria. A workaround involves converting both the Criteria and TextCriteria objects to its Document representations, adding it to a BasicDbList and then converting back to a "$or" Criteria object.

```
TextCriteria textCriteria = TextCriteria.forDefaultLanguage().matchingAny("570-11024");
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("productDetails.code").is("572-R110");

BasicDBList bsonList = new BasicDBList();
bsonList.add(criteria.getCriteriaObject());
bsonList.add(textCriteria.getCriteriaObject());

Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(new Criteria("$or").is(bsonList));
mongoTemplate.find(query, YourEntity.class);
```

PS: Someone has raised this issue in the spring-data-mongodb repo with a proposed fix by
changing the parameter types of orOperator from Criteria to CriteriaDefinition.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues/3895.